# What kind of syntax/technology is used to count items in the cart in a MVC 4 Application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a class `Cart`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Cart
    {
        [Key]
        public int      RecordId    { get; set; }
        public string   CartId      { get; set; }
        public int      AlbumId     { get; set; }
        public int      Count       { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public virtual Album Album  { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and there is a class `ShoppingCart` where business logic is coded. Inside it there is the method `GetCount()` which I don't understand at all.

```
   public int GetCount()
        {
            // Get the count of each item in the cart and sum them up
            int? count = (from cartItems in storeDB.Carts
                          where cartItems.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                          select (int?)cartItems.Count).Sum();
            // Return 0 if all entries are null
            return count ?? 0;
        }
```

1. What is `int?`?
2. Is it LINQ query, SQL query or what kind of query inside because it looks like SQL but it uses something what is looking like casting.

EDIT: Second question refers to: `(from cartItems in storeDB.Carts
                              where cartItems.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                              select (int?)cartItems.Count).Sum();` not to `int?`

It is from this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8

Comment: int? is what they call a nullable in c#. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx In c# value types cannot be null so this is a way of accepting null with a value type.

Comment: @MikeCheel Ok so that was easy part it's like an `Integer` in java.

Comment: The type? syntax is short hand for Nullable<T> where T is a value type. So no it is not like an Integer. It is a generic object that wraps a value type (like integer) and provides a way to say that there is no value (via null).

Comment: @GrantWinney Yeah. I don't get this query it looks like SQL but it is not. What is it?

Comment: @Yoda its called language integrated query (aka LINQ).

Answer (score 1):

int? is a nullable type.  The function is utilizing this in the case where it does not find anything matching the where statement. When he returns count ?? 0, he's coalescing the count, stating that if it is null, return 0 instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. `int?` is short for `Nullable<int>` and is a way to make the non-nullable primitive type `int` nullable. `Nullable<T>` is a `struct` (which on themselves can't be `null` too, since it is a `struct`). To make this work though, the code is converted at compile time into other calls on `Nullable<T>`.
2. That is a [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) statement that 'by design' looks a lot like SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The inner-query is LINQ "query" syntax. The parentheses are not casting anything... they denote an inner-query that will return a result set, which will then be processed by the `Sum()` method (LINQ "method" syntax).

If it makes it clearer, you could split it up:

```
var results = from cartItems in storeDB.Carts
              where cartItems.CartId == ShoppingCartId
              select (int?)cartItems.Count;

var sum = results.Sum();
```

Or all in method syntax:

```
var results = storeDB.Carts
                     .Where(c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId)
                     .Select(c => (int?)c.Count)
                     .Sum();
```

I don't believe there's any reason to check if `Sum()` returns a null value (using `??`) because the `Sum()` method for nullable ints ignores null values.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156065.aspx):

> This method returns zero if source contains no elements.
>
> The result does not include values that are null.

Probably not much point in addressing the nullable int question, since the other answers/comments already have, but [here's a decent page that shows it in use](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-int).

Answer (score 1):

```
public int GetCount()
{
    // Get the count of each item in the cart and sum them up
    int? count = (from cartItems in storeDB.Carts
                      where cartItems.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                      select (int?)cartItems.Count).Sum();
    // Return 0 if all entries are null
    return count ?? 0;
}
```

`int?` is shorthand for writing `Nullable<int>`.  It means that the result can be an integer, or it can be `null`.

The query is a linq query.  It is using the [LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386964%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) provider which will transform that query into SQL, and return the results back into `int? count`

The bottom line `return count ?? 0;` is just shorthand for saying

```
if (count == null)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    return count;
}
```